# Creating a set of arrays from function and passing it to datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to access information from two different sources.

The first with the getter function `idElement` returns an **id**. This id is used to access `idMoreAtr` which returns the **name** and **age** of this element.

My plan was to iterate over all elements of `idElement`, and save the name and age into an array so to later print on a datatable.

However, when I try the table is empty. I think it has to do with callbacks or scope, but I'm not sure what is going on or how to fix it.

If we console.log(set) inside the function the array works fine but when I try to access it outside the function it appears to be empty.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
      var  count = 5;
      let set = [];

      function add(name, age) {
        set.push({
          name: name,
          age: age
        });
      };

      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        idElement.call(i, function(error, id) {
          if (error)
            console.error(error);
          else {
            idMoreAtr(id, function(error, result) {
              if (error) {
                console.log(errorMsg);
                return;
              }
              var name;
              var age;
              name = result[0];
              age = result[1].toNumber();
              add(name, age);
            });
          }
        });
      };

      $('#table').DataTable({
        data: set,
        columns: [{
            title: "Name"
          },
          {
            title: "Age"
          }
        ]
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="table" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Please attach `idElement` and `idMoreAttr` elements to your code.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski they are two basic getters that i retrieve from a ethereum smart contract. I only have the JSON available for them